# Customizar página de erro para connect timed out no Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

Estou tentando criar uma pagina de erro amigável para o caso do LDAP estar fora do ar, mas infelizmente a única resposta que tenho é a `j_spring_security_check`.

Tentei mapear a exceção no `web.xml`, mas não tive sucesso.

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.net.SocketTimeoutException</exception-type >
    <location>/408</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.net.SocketTimeoutException</exception-type >
    <location>/408</location>
</error-page>
```

Erro no console:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/gpa-pesquisa] threw exception org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: 171.18.0.15:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: 171.18.0.15:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:108)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:356)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:357)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:309)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:616)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:586)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:1651)
    at br.ufc.quixada.npi.ldap.dao.LdapUsuarioDao.getByCpf(LdapUsuarioDao.java:76)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, eu fiz o seguinte para crias as paginas de erros personalizáveis.
Uso o Tiles Apache para gerenciar minhas views.

web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/500</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

IndexController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/404")
public String pageNotFound(Model model) {
    return "base.admin.error.404";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/500")
public String internalServerError(Model model) {
    return "base.admin.error.500";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, no meu caso tava dando erro porque tinha mapeado no controlador o erro 500 apenas para o método GET e deveria mapear tanto para o GET quanto para o POST.